# Is there any way to re-enable the “old style” iTunes metadata editing window in version 12.1.0.50?

Tags: macos, itunes, metadata

**Short Question:** Versions of iTunes 12 previously allowed users to use the “old style” iTunes metadata editing window layout when clicking <kbd>alt/option</kbd> and selecting “Get Info…”. That has seemingly disappeared with a recent update to iTunes 12; specifically version 12.1.0.50. Is there any way to re-enable the “old style” metadata editing window in this new version of iTunes 12.1.0.50.

**Long Question:** So, when iTunes 12 was released the interface was changed a bit; which is expected. But unlike older releases, it included a change to the metadata editing window which made it more compact and altered the user experience.

Some of us still like the “old style” editing window layout and the user experience connected to it. Heck the “old style” window has been like that for years. But prior to iTunes 12.1.0.50—and still using iTunes 12—one could access the “old style” metadata editing window by doing a “Get Info…” on media while holding down the <kbd>alt/option</kbd>. [This blog post](http://www.mcelhearn.com/display-the-old-fashioned-info-window-in-itunes-12/) explains the simple trick nicely and below is a screenshot of the “old style” metadata editing window for reference.

Now with iTunes 12.1.0.50 it seems that this somewhat hidden—yet easy to access—functionality is gone. Unless I am missing something? Does anyone know how to reenable the “old style” metadata editing window in iTunes 12.1.0.50? Or is it simply gone and ripped from the core code forever?

[image]

Comment: It was redesigned and yes it is gone and not there as it was in the older versions. most people did not like the old version and what you say is gone so most people are happy but for your case its "simply gone and ripped from the core code forever?".....

Comment: You can still use <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to get info. What options do you miss, it's just redesigned.

Answer (score 1):

No, it has been completely removed.

Answer (score -2):

It's still there.

Press <kbd>Opt</kbd> while right-clicking on the track and selecting `Get info`.